# Typesetting New Functions in LaTeX

Tags: latex, typesetting

So, I just have a little question:

What is the "best way" to typeset new functions in LaTeX which aren't already included in the various packages?  Right now I'm just using `\mbox` as my go-to method,  but I just was wondering if there was a more "acceptable way of doing it (as with mbox, I have to make sure to include spaces around the text of the functions in order for it to not look too strange)

Here is an example:

```
$y(t)=2e^{1/2}\sqrt{\pi}\mbox{Erfi }(t)$
```

which comes out looking like:

[$y(t)=2e^{1/2}\sqrt{\pi}\mbox{Erfi }(t)$ http://adamnbowen.com/images/error_function.jpg](http://adamnbowen.com/images/error_function.jpg)

Don't get me wrong... I think it looks fine, but I was just looking for some opinions (as far as best practices go).

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\DeclareMathOperator` from package `amsmath`. For example,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\erfi{Erfi}

\begin{document}
Consider $x + y + \erfi(t) = z$ for example.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: result]

If you only need it once, you can also use `\operatorname`: you get the same output as above with

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Consider $x + y + \operatorname{Erfi}(t) = z$ for example.
\end{document}
```

If you cannot use the `amsmath` package for some reason, you can manually do `\mathop{\mathrm{Erfi}}` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Consider $x + y + \mathop{\mathrm{Erfi}}(t) = z$ for example.
\end{document}
```

See the always-useful TeX FAQ, specifically [Defining a new log-like function in LaTeX](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-newfunction).

Comment: An example might help future readers:
`\DeclareMathOperator\erfi{Erfi}`

Comment: @Dalker Thanks, updated the answer (I had no memory of writing this answer 15 years ago).